# Getting the Correct Position of a Selected Text in a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am have a requirement where I have to find the position of selected text inside a content-editable div. Once I select a word of the text, I highlight it by surrounding that word by a span with some css in it. I also get the starting position of the highlighted word.

The problem is that If I have already highlighted a word at index 0 and after that I try to select/highlight a word that is for example at index 10 of the div, the position I get is wrong.

Here is a picture for reference:

[image]

See how the highlighted word "Position" is being reported back to me as being on index 1, when clearly it should be 8.

Here is my code to pick up the position of the selected text:

```
var sel, range;
if (window.getSelection) {
  sel = window.getSelection();
  if (sel.rangeCount) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
    return range.startOffset;
  }
}
else {
  return null;
}
```

I will really appreciate your help on this. Thanks

Comment: by position I guess you mean by character? because of it's by word then it's totally accurate

Comment: @SamCreamer I need to get the start index of the selected word's first character.

Answer (score 1):

When you select inside the contenteditable div, `getSelection()` returns a `Selection` object with an `anchornode` type of "text". That is, you're selecting the text node of the containing `div`. When your div looks like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">Testing Position of Preview</div>
```

the text node is the only child node of the div.

However, once you make a selection and mark it up with a `span`:

```
<div contenteditable="true"><span class="marked">Testing</span> Position of Preview</div>
```

you now have **three** descendant nodes of the div: The span, the text node inside the span, and the text node inside the div. Therefore, when you get the range of the selection object returned after selecting the word "Position", it is returning the range relative to the div's text node, which has contents of

```
" Position of Preview"
```

(note the space before the word "Position").

So, the offset of "Position" is 1 from the beginning of its anchor node, as reported.

Comment: How can I get the position of the text not relative to the div's textnode? Or is it not possible in this case?

Comment: It's definitely not going to be easy using just the `Selection` object. Also consider what happens if a selection includes an already marked-up range such that the Selection object now contains more than one node.

Comment: Any way of coming across this? I mean what could I use in combination with the Selection object?

Comment: I'm not aware of any single API you could use. You could either reconstruct the nodes based on the Selection object, or, if you absolutely must count the text outside the context of their formatting nodes, use pattern matching on the root node's `innerText` property.